# Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos, xcode-command-line-tools

i updated os 12.3 to 13.1, xcode 13.1 to 14.1 and installed commandline tools, react native app running through xcode but not running with command line, getting below error

```
    2022-12-13 16:36:47.584 xcodebuild[3616:20381] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/zn/6l6295m57kb3vn_8pyn8xtbr0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2022-13-12_16-36-0047.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -find simctl 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH
error Could not get the simulator list from Xcode. Please open Xcode and try running project directly from there to resolve the remaining issues.
Error: Command failed: xcrun simctl list --json devices
2022-12-13 16:36:47.584 xcodebuild[3616:20381] Writing error result bundle to /var/folders/zn/6l6295m57kb3vn_8pyn8xtbr0000gn/T/ResultBundle_2022-13-12_16-36-0047.xcresult
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -find simctl 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:828:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:863:15)
```

but react native app running fine if run this command `export SDKROOT=$(xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)` before running `react-native run-ios`, if i close the terminal and run again the react native app it is showing same error again

i tried these steps

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Did you load the correct simulator if it is not provided in the Settings -> Platform Tab

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi i finally found the issue, my `.zshrc` file pointing to older sdk, i removed `SDKROOT` path in `.zshrc` file and did run `export SDKROOT=$(xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)` in terminal, issue resolved for me

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same problem and resolved it in the following steps.

1. Open Xcode
2. go to preferences
3. go to locations tab
4. select an Xcode version in the select labeled "Command Line Tools"

Comment: It's worth nothing that my Xcode 14 preferences showed the right version selected, but selecting it again made things start working.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the accepted answer is to create a symLink as shared [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667561).

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk
```